# What objectives are there for Temple Run 2 level 10?

Tags: temple-run-2

I am currently on Level 10 of Temple Run 2, and I have not seen a list of the missions to be completed and I do not know what my objectives to complete Level 10 are as at now. What are the missions to be completed in level 10 of Temple Run 2?

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon your version.  For some earlier versions, level 10 was the maximum level and there were no further possible objectives.   But for more recent versions (1.20.1 of Feb 2016, for example), there have been additional objectives beyond level 10 and those appear in the "Objectives" list from the menu page, along with possibly some progress bar for objectives that may take a while to complete.  At some point, they added an "All Objectives Complete!" message when you have completed all possible objectives and reached the top level, but it sounds like you may have an earlier version where that is not indicated.